# Provide Google Analytics 4 access to one subdomains data only

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

My web app gives each paying customer their own private subdomain, e.g.:

- customer1.mysite.com
- customer2.mysite.com
- etc

Currently all subdomains use the same GA4 tag. No properties exist.

Is it possible to give an employee from "customer2" access so they can only see their subdomain's data?

Thanks